# Cannot install python-minimal on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, ubuntu-17.10

I have been trying to install python-minimal on Ubuntu 17.10 but getting this error.

```
sudo apt-get install python-minimal

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-minimal is already the newest version (2.7.14-2ubuntu1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.14-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried install using .deb file but still no luck.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: It states that python-minimal is already the newest version. Could it be possible it was installed if you check `sudo apt list --installed | grep -i python`?

Comment: Try removing it first?

Comment: This sounds more suitable for https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Fernando No it is not installed, treid the command and python-minimal is not coming

Answer (score 0):

The older installation may be broken. So try to reinstall with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal
sudo apt-get upgrade
```